# How do I write a regex function in Python that checks if a user has only letters and numbers?

Tags: python, regex, string

I only want my usernames to have letters, numbers, and underscores. No other symbols, spaces, or anything else.

How can I write a regex to check if it's only letters/numbers/underscores?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> re.match('^\w+$', '4tg25g_3yg')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f8093f198b8>
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")
if regex.match(some_string):
    do_something()
```

Comment: `A-Z` has a musty old code-smell to it, possibly even a moribund one.

Answer (score 2):

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

or

```
"^[\w_]+$"
```

Comment: The `_` is redundant in the second one, by the way. `\w` already includes it in python (and any sane regex engine, really).

Comment: Those are not equivalent. Also, **any pattern that has a literal `A-Z` or `a-z` in it is virtually always wrong, sometimes.** It has a code-smell to it. For many reasons `\w` is much, *much* better, since if it’s compliant with [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) it matches any code point with the Alphabetic, Mark, Decimal Number, or Connector Punctuation property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
import re
if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$", user_string):
    # do something here
```

Comment: Ideally, you would use '+' to ensure that the username contains at least one character. Otherwise blank usernames would be accepted.