# Testing string for characters that are not letters or numbers

Tags: python, string

I have a string like `'H897b Site'`, and I want to test that string to make sure it only contains letters and numbers and no special characters.

So in cases like `'H897b Sit$e'` and `'H8(&b Site'` I want to be able to flag it.

What I am trying to accomplish is to loop through a column in a table and check for typing errors from the data entry person.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: do spaces count as letter and numbers?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, spaces are fine. In my example above, the space is acceptable. The first part of the string before the space is the is the actual site name. The ' Site' will always come after the actual site name. Does that clear up your question?

Comment: Mike: @Marc is right and _your_ question is what is not constructive. See the Stack Exchange [Community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) about asking questions. All see [Why are some questions closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/closed-questions).

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89909/in-python-how-to-i-verify-that-a-string-only-contains-letters-numbers-undersco http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944438/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-alphanumeric-characters-and-dashes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939669/how-do-i-write-a-regex-function-in-python-that-checks-if-a-user-has-only-letters

Answer (score 1):

You can loops through the string and make checks like

```
if 'z' >= c >= 'a'
```

Similarly for numerals etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    print all(part.isalnum() for part in my_string.split())
```